# Validation for max amount in input tag : (Aurelia)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, aurelia

***I have an input tag on Web Page where the `variable` amount is bounded to the input tag. So whatever value we enter to input tag will get binded with the same `variable` i.e amount.***

```
<input value.bind ="amount" ></input>
```

*What I want is to make validations for the max amount to be entered to that input tag . Lets say I want max amount to be `99`.So I should not be allowing the user to enter the more amount than 99 . Say if in case he tries to enter `100` only `10` should get entered the next `0` should not be allowed to enter there.But always we should not disable the input tag at any point , it alwasys should be editable*

Comment: A nice alternative is `<input type="range" min="0" max="99" value.bind="amount" />`. It limits your numeric range by design and also looks nice. Notice that each browser may implement it differently. Examples [here](https://html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php).

Comment: Would it even work if i try putting decimal values . and also we should only allow user toput  only two values after decimal point. like 98.99 it should be less than 99

Comment: Not for decimals AFAIK.

Comment: Thats what i want .. any alternative ??

Comment: Look into using `observable` in your view-model.  Basically, you can observe the `amount` property for changes and, when it's changed, perform whatever logic you want to make sure the property conforms to what you need it to be.  Aurelia's two-way binding will make sure the DOM reflects the change.  Here are some docs: http://aurelia.io/docs/binding/binding-observable-properties#introduction

Comment: Thanks dude ... would go through it

Comment: But again a concern ... i just have current value, what u said was possible if i had some value initially in my variable .. so i would have catched the event of any change in currently held value in that variable

Comment: @SandeepPandey I don't quite understand the concern... can you rephrase?  Also, feel free to use this gist to play around with `observable`: https://gist.run/?id=508074fc5a493214635a1ad15d95b35c.  (Obviously the logic within the `amountChanged` method isn't exactly what you need, but this should help get you there).

Answer (score 2):

Aurelia is built on standards. Its binding syntax can be used to hook into any native Javascript event. Taking this in consideration, one thing that comes to mind is hook into the keypress/keydown events to allow or disallow certain characters.

Combine that with an observable (@bindable) that validates the min/max values of your `amount` field, you might want to look into something like:

```
<template>
    <input type="text" 
    value.bind="amount" 
    keypress.trigger="validate($event)">
</template>
```

```js
import { bindable } from "aurelia-framework";

export class App {
  @bindable public amount: number;

  public amountChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
    // limit the amount to a min/max value
    if (newValue < 0 || newValue > 99) {
      this.amount = oldValue;
    }
  }

  public validate(args: KeyboardEvent) {
    // simplified validation, in this case for numbers only
    // allow/disallow anything you like here (like decimal seperators)
    if (args.keyCode < 48 || args.keyCode > 57)
    {
      args.preventDefault();
      return;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Note that the sample above is TypeScript flavoured.
**Update:** I've added a vanilla Javascript [gist to play with](https://gist.run/?id=99e4f6c9bacf45dfd762bef36d21746a).

Now the validation itself is far from ideal. In this case, all non-numeric keys are also blocked, including the decimal separators. You might want to add support for this yourself. Control keys, like backspace and delete etc. still work, though.

In any case, this might be a good starting point in solving your original request:

- Binding the value to a property and adding a min/max validation on it
- Disallowing certain keys/values, in this case limit to numbers
- Retain the original value if validation failed

Comment: tried but amountChanged function is getting called only once at the time of first assignment of value to the amount. on every keypress i want it to be invoked. Is it possible ?

Comment: @SandeepPandey It should do just that. For this, I've updated the answer [with a gist](https://gist.run/?id=99e4f6c9bacf45dfd762bef36d21746a). Does that help?